# Reorder DOM elements on different screen sizes

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to create a component with a text on the left or right side and an image next to it.

[image]

Currently I just use a bool parameter to check which element comes first. On larger screen sizes everything is fine but when it comes to smaller ones every image should be above the text.

If the text is on the left side this doesn't work because it places itself above the image.

I created an working example showing the problem

https://codesandbox.io/s/3qpj23y3o1

How can I fix this behaviour? Maybe there is a way getting rid of this if statement too? Because the only thing that differs is the order of the image and the text container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're working with CSS grid you could do it simply by using `grid-template-areas` and create your areas `img` and `txt` :

```
   .textImageSectionContainer {
      ...
      grid-template-areas:'img' 'txt';

    }
    .imgContainer {
       ....
       grid-area:img;
      }
     .txtContainer {
       padding: 50px;
       grid-area:txt;
      }
```

you could apply the above rules for small sizes only, in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/l9k8m6ozkl) example i set the above rules for screen size under 700px

**Update**:

You could use class binding to avoid the `if` statement and redundant code :

```
<template>
  <div
    :class="{ imgleft: imageLeft, imgright: !imageLeft }"
    class="textImageSectionContainer"
  >
    <div class="imgContainer"><img :src="imgUrl" class="img" /></div>
    <div class="txtContainer">
      <div class="headerText">{{ headerText }}</div>
      <div class="mainText">{{ mainText }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

and CSS rules should be like :

```
.imgleft {
  display: flex;
}

.imgright {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for :) do you know if I could get rid of the big if statement within that template?

Comment: @Question3r which statement?

Comment: the if statement at the top of my template component

Comment: @Question3r i updated my answer and the codesandox code

Comment: I keep learning things about CSS from you Boussadjra. Keep it up bro :)